# How to implement a generalized uniqueness DB constraint (A,B) and (B,A) in Django?

Tags: django, django-signals, django-constraints

I want to check the database before an object is created with fields one='a' and two='b', and not create (throw an exception) if the database already has rows with fields one='b' and two='a' (reverse order).  That is, guarantee that only one of (one, two) and (two, one) exists. It's like a generalized uniqueness constraint.

I'm using Django 3.2.

I see [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.CheckConstraint.check) supports a boolean [Expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression), and one type of expression is an aggregate.  So I can imagine testing that the number of rows with (one, two) and (two, one) is at most 1.  However, that sounds expensive, and I also don't see examples of how to use a Count in the CheckConstraint.

Alternatively, I could implement a [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal that issues a query.  This seems better, as I'll have the data in hand to form the query.  However, I don't see how to prevent the save using the pre_save signal.
Does it have a return value I can use?  I don't see that in the docs.

**EDIT**: A third alternative might be overriding `save` to do the check.

I'm open to other ideas as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django unique together constraint in two directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546651/django-unique-together-constraint-in-two-directions)

Comment: It is indeed the same question, but does not answer. In a comment there: "in some future version UniqueConstraints (Django docs) are going to support expressions, so you can write some expression that concatenates the two fields with some separator and in some order, effectively achieving what you want." Well, UniqueConstraints support expressions, but I don't understand how to use them to solve this problem. That's actually in my question above.

Comment: Unique constraints don't support [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#expressions) yet... That is part of Django 4.0 which is expected to release in December 2021. (Note: That comment in that question was by me :p)

Comment: Oh, I got confused. It's CheckConstraint-s which support expressions. Thanks for that info. I'll close this, then.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any database-level constraints that would allow this type of constraint.

So the constraint could be implemented at the application level. Are you creating the model when a form is submitted? In that case, you could check for an existing row in the database in the form validation code.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer to check at the model level rather than the form level. Perhaps I might override `save`.